# Nexus/Gradle lock specifc versions

Tags: gradle, nexus, sonatype

We are using gradle as a build tool and sonatype nexus to store project thirdparty and public artifacts.

There was a recent update to a public artifact say com.abc:cde:3.4.2, wherein our project uses com.abc:cde:3.4.1

However,  during the build execution, gradle pulls the latest version of the artifact even though the build is explicitly specified to download only 3.4.1

```
compile 'com.abc:cde:3.4.1'
```

Is there a way to download only specific version of dependency even though nexus has the latest version of artifacts

Comment: What you describe is not really possible, unless some other component pulls in the newer version of the artifact. You can use `gradle dependencies` to find out where it comes from.

Comment: Good to know about gradle dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force version numbers by using a resolution strategy on a configuration.

e.g.

```
configurations.compile {
  resolutionStrategy {
      force 'com.abc:cde:3.4.1'
  }
}
```

Check out https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks, is it the gradle best practice to force versions for every required dependency?  I also found we can also force the versions from the dependency handler however resolution strategy always takes a precedence. This sounds like a downside of gradle in depend handling vs maven. Maven takes versions in pom as precedence so I dont have to force them explicitly.